# StackOverflowError on recursive algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, stack-overflow

I'm trying to code a recursive algorithm in order to generate a valid board(unique solution) for a game called *kakuro*.
When executing the program I keep getting a StackOverflowError. I tried debugging my code and it is working as expected, but it suddenly crashes in a non recursive method. I have been reading about this issue on the internet and I have already checked that I don't make two recursive calls with the same parameters. This algorithm tries different values for certain squares and (when every square has its own value, it should thus try every possible combination of values for those squares) solves it in order to see whether it has an unique solution.

```
 private boolean generarKakuroRecursivo(ArrayList<Negra> noColocados, Casella[][] tablero){
        if (noColocados.size() == 0 ){
            System.out.println(getStringTablero());
            if (kakuroUnico(tablero)){
                this.tauler = tablero;
                return true;
            }
            else return false; 
        }
        
        Negra casillaNegra = noColocados.get(0);

        boolean fila = casillaNegra.getFila() == 0 && casillaNegra.getCoords().getElement1()+1 < dimensio && this.tauler[casillaNegra.getCoords().getElement0()][casillaNegra.getCoords().getElement1()+1].getTipus() == 'B';
        boolean columna = casillaNegra.getColumna() == 0 && casillaNegra.getCoords().getElement0()+1 < dimensio && this.tauler[casillaNegra.getCoords().getElement0()+1][casillaNegra.getCoords().getElement1()].getTipus() == 'B';
        ArrayList <Pair<Integer, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> >> posibilidadesNegra = calcularPosibilidades(casillaNegra);

        //CALCULAMOS LOS POSIBLES NUMEROS PARA LA CASILLA NEGRA QUE HEMOS COGIDO

        int index1 = casillaNegra.getCoords().getElement0(), index2 = casillaNegra.getCoords().getElement1();
        for (Pair<Integer, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> > posibilidad : posibilidadesNegra){
            int valor = posibilidad.getElement0();
            if (fila && columna){
                colocarNegra(((Negra)tablero[index1][index2]), valor, true);
                noColocados.get(0).setNumFil(valor); //poner fila =false
            } //actualizar restricciones
            else if(fila){
                colocarNegra(((Negra)tablero[index1][index2]), valor, true);
                noColocados.remove(0);
            }
            else if (columna){
                colocarNegra(((Negra)tablero[index1][index2]), valor, false);
                noColocados.remove(0);
            }
            if (generarKakuroRecursivo(noColocados, tablero)) return true;
            else{
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     if (!noColocados.contains(casillaNegra)) noColocados.add(casillaNegra);
                if (fila){
                    retirarNegra((Negra)tablero[index1][index2],true);
                    if (!noColocados.contains(casillaNegra)) noColocados.add(casillaNegra);
                }

                else if (columna) {
                    retirarNegra((Negra)tablero[index1][index2], false);
                    if (!noColocados.contains(casillaNegra)) noColocados.add(casillaNegra);
                }

            }
        } //Caso recursivo

        //PROBAMOS RECURSIVAMENTE TODAS LAS OPCIONES

        return false;
}
```

This is the recursive function in discuss, noColocados is an ArrayList which contains the squares (belonging to tablero) where we want to try all the possible combinations (if one of those combinations generates a unique solution(it should happen) the algorithm stops).

[Boards generated by the algorithm before crashing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBKcu.png)

As you can see in the picture above, the algorithm works well until it crashes.

[Debug information of the crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cILx.png)

In this picture you can see where the StackOverflowError is triggered, as you can see calculaNumCells is a non recursive method.

Edit: I also tried not parsing the parameter *tablero* as it was unnecessary (it is the same as the implicit parameter of the class) to the recursive algorithm nor other methods like *CalculaNumCells*.
Anyway the execution keeps crashing in the same exact point that it was crashing before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A StackOverflowError merely indicates that there’s no space available in the stack for a new frame. In your case, the recursive calls still fill up most of the stack but, since the method calls other methods besides itself, those can also exhaust the stack.

If, for example, your recursive method called only itself, the stack would always be exhausted when calling that one method.

Comment: so... how can I solve this issue? are the methods being called by the recursive algorithm a problem then?

Comment: No, the root issue is that the stack size is not enough for the amount of recursion required. Ideally, you’d rewrite the algorithm to use a loop instead of recursion. Pragmatically, you might get away by increasing stack size.

Comment: I tried increasing the stack size from 2048MB to 16384MB and the program still crashes in the exact same part. How is it possible that the StackoverflowError is triggered in the same recursive call if the stack size's different?

Comment: Since the program recurses, most of the stack trace will be a pattern, repeated over and over. Do you have any estimation of how deep the recursion needs to be to arrive at a solution?